# Unescape XML with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to set an XML value to an input field in thymeleaf.
I have tried:

1. ${#strings.unescapeJava(str)}
2. th:field
3. th:value

and all values in the thymeleaf documentation none of them is working. th:utext works fine but this is not setting the Xml data as value of the input field.   issue is that thymeleaf keeps escaping the XML tags but I actually need the actual XML I sent to thymeleaf from my controller as the value for my input field.
Kindly advise on how to achieve this.

Here is my input field:

```
<input name="xml_data" type="hidden" th:field="${tranx.split}" />
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: I suspect you're dealing with some other problem than the one you think you are. It doesn't make any sense to have unescaped XML inside a value attribute or you won't have a well-formed HTML document. What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have resolved it actually. Issue is with my JAXB configuration not thymeleaf. Thanks for dropping by @Peter